# Emoji disappear when I print, export to pdf, or download a pdf after update to 20.04

Tags: 20.04, emoji

I recently updated to 20.04 and I love the new full range of full color emoji but they disappear when I print, export to PDF or even if I download a pdf from email.

I thought it was a libre office issue at first until I noticed them disappear from the downloaded PDF. In the screencapture is a Libre office spreadsheet print preview screen full of emoji, and on the right is what I get if I export to PDF or print.

[image: screencapture]

I have verified that "objects/images" is checked in LibreOffice, tried from a fresh file, and tried it in LibreOffice's safe mode.
Please help.

Comment: It may depend on which app you view the PDF file with. This looks like the default Evince document viewer. Do the emoji appear if you open the file with your browser, or with LibreOffice Draw, or Gimp...?

Comment: interesting. so if i open the pdf with chrome they disappear, but if i use LibreOffice Draw they are there. i did notice that my Printer Language type is "Automatic : PDF"

Comment: i dont have gimp. but i did email the pdf to my wife whose windows computer did not display the emoji

Comment: i installed and tried Atril Document Viewer with the same result.

Answer (score 6):

Until this [bug](https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=129523) is fixed, the work arounds [seem to be](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=331811) exporting to PNG rather than PDF or replacing the emojis with symbols from the Symbola font (which are black and white).

Comment: Exporting as an image is not viable since there will be no hyperlinks available.

Answer (score 1):

A valid workaround consists in uploading the LibreOffice file (eg ODT) to Google Docs and printing from Google Docs.

Another workaround is to save the odt document to `.txt`, then open the txt document with Text Editor, and print from there.  Have done this with WhatsApp Chats, and works brilliantly.

Comment: This works fine. However, be careful because it may destroy some other stuff, like the slides numbers that you will have to add again.

Answer (score 0):

It [was written](https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/214397/which-fonts-to-install-in-order-to-save-emoticons-in-a-pdf-file/) that it is a bug:

https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=129523